# How does Python 3 buffer big int objects?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-2.x, cpython

When reading the CPython source code of Python 2, we can find `PyIntBlock` in [intobject.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/89d47911209b/Objects/intobject.c).

In Python 3, there is no intobject.c, integer objects are created by [longobject.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4232eb53a036/Objects/longobject.c). In this file, we can find small int buffer pool `small_ints`, which is the same as `small_ints` in Python 2.

However, I can't find something like `PyIntBlock`. And here is the question: how does Python 3 buffer big integer objects? If there is no such mechanism in Python 3, will it be slow?

Comment: I don't think Python pools integer objects larger than those in the small integer pool.

Comment: Questions about CPython might be better asked on the python.org python-list, mirrored as gmane.comp.python.general at news.gmane.org.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a newcomer, so I don't know where is the best place to ask such a question.